# How can I secure the amount field when using paypal IPN?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I have created a wordpress plugin which creates paypal buy now button and uses paypal IPN ... Here is my code for the form

```
$output =   '<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$paypalID.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.$return_url.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="'.$currency.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$product_name.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="p'.$product_id.'" value="'.$product_price.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$responderID.'">
                            <input name="notify_url" value="'.plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'ipn_sandbox.php" type="hidden">
                            <input type="image" src="'.$upload_image.'" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!"> 
                        </form>';
```

The issue is ... When submitting the information to paypal the user can easily change the price of the product and send the wrong price to paypal .. for example if the product is worth $10 the user can use inspect element and change the price to $1 or whatever the user likes and send it to paypal .. Is there any way to prevent this or secure the price field .. Thanks

There is a solution that I have found ... I have added this javascript code right below the form and it working ... but the issue now is that if I place multiple buttons on one page (Let's say two buttons on one page) both of the buttons stop working unless the given is same for both the buttons For example

```
$output .= "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){var a=".$product_price.";jQuery('form[name=_xclick]').submit(function(c){var b=jQuery('input[id=p".$product_id."]').val();if(b==a){return}else{c.preventDefault()}})});</script>";
```

if price of Button 1 = $20 and Price of Button 2 = $20 then both the buttons will work..

BUT

If price of Button 1 = $20 and Price of Button 2 = $21 then both the buttons won't work..

Any Suggestions/Ideas ??

Comment: Uhm ? you check the price from your database with the one returned by  IPN ?

Comment: Given my scenario i think the price should be checked before submitting it to paypal using their buy now button .. Is there a way I can do that ??

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to go about this. If you're using fixed prices for fixed products/services that don't change, you can [create encrypted payment buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0N30Y4) on PayPal's website.

Alternatively, in your PHP script that receives the IPN notification, you can check that the amount in `$_POST['mc_gross']` matches the amount you expect it to be.

Comment: Well it is a plugin which creates product .. I mean one button for product so the prices are fixed for every button ...

Comment: The main takeaway is that you cannot create encrypted buttons *dynamically*, you have to actually go to the PayPal website each time you want to create one. So that limits its usefulness in some circumstances. At any rate, to be absolutely sure you should ALWAYS be checking the data in the IPN before processing orders, shipping items, etc.